# Clojure: Split a sequence into top-n and rest?

Tags: clojure

I'd like split a sequence into it's top-n elements and the rest. Here's an inefficient implementation using the built in sort and split-at:

```
> (defn split-top-n
    [n comp coll]
    (split-at n (sort comp coll)))

> (split-top-n 2 #(- %2 %1) (list 6.2 5.1 88.0 90.1 1.2 16.9))
[(90.1 88.0) (16.9 6.2 5.1 1.2)]
```

Is there an efficient Clojure built-in for this? Or do I need to write my own?

Comment: Why it isn't efficient?

Comment: Mostly because it does a full sort on the collection before taking the top-n. To illustrate, take the case where n is 1, then split-top-n is only looking for the greatest element in a collection, which only requires a single scan of the collection rather than a full sort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such function in the standard library. The simple implementation that you've already written is actually only inefficient for the special case of small values of `n`, but perfectly fine in the general case.

As long as you don't know that this function in its current implementation is really a significant performance bottleneck in your complete application, it's probably a waste of effort to write a more complicate version.

**EDIT**: Thinking somewhat more about this, it might be worth a try to write an implementation that coerces the sequence into a vector and then does an in-place *Quickselect* to partition the `n` best elements to the beginning of the vector. That should be relatively easy to do and could provide a reasonable better performance as long as your pivot elements are well chosen.

**EDIT 2**: I decided to try that implementation myself. It worked fine with some simple test cases, but I'm not completely sure that there are no off-by-one bugs in this that might trigger in some edge cases:

```
(defn split-top-n
  [n comp coll]
  (let [v (transient (vec coll))]
    (loop [start 0, end (count v)]
      (when (> end n)
        (let [pos (loop [i (inc start), pos start]
                    (if (< i end)
                      (if (comp (v i) (v start))
                        (let [pos* (inc pos)]
                          (assoc! v, i (v pos*), pos* (v i))
                          (recur (inc i) pos*))
                        (recur (inc i) pos))
                      (do
                        (assoc! v, start (v pos), pos (v start))
                        pos)))]
          (if (< pos n)
            (recur (inc pos) end)
            (recur start pos)))))
    (split-at n (persistent! v))))
```

Clarification: this expects a simple boolean comparator function for `comp` instead of one of the negative/zero/positive number kind.

**EDIT 3**: I took another look at the documentation for transients and noticed that I was exploiting undefined behaviour. It may actually be the case that the above version will actually always work as expected, but a correct version should nonetheless respect the language documentation. I will leave the previous version in this answer in place because the answer was already accepted with it, but here's a version that's using the return value of `assoc!` as the documentation demands:

```
(defn swap-in!
  [v i j]
  (assoc! v, i (v j), j (v i)))

(defn quickpartition!
  [comp v start end]
  (loop [v v, i (inc start), pos start]
    (if (< i end)
      (if (comp (v i) (v start))
        (recur (swap-in! v i (inc pos)) (inc i) (inc pos))
        (recur v (inc i) pos))
      [(swap-in! v start pos) pos])))

(defn split-top-n
  [n comp coll]
  (loop [v (transient (vec coll)), start 0, end (count v)]
    (if (> end n)
      (let [[v* pos] (quickpartition! comp v start end)]
        (if (< pos n)
          (recur v* (inc pos) end)
          (recur v* start pos)))
      (split-at n (persistent! v)))))
```

**EDIT 4**: The bad readability of the earlier version still itched me, so I have now split my implementation into multiple functions.

Comment: Thank you. This is the sort of implementation I was expecting to find as a built in. I'm surprised to find [few languages have a built-in Selection Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Language_support).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a data structure such as sorted-set which it is currently implemented as ***clojure.lang.PersistentTreeSet***.  This way you can avoid the sorting before you get your top n elements (I would say).

```
(-> (sorted-set-by >) 
    (conj 90) 
    (conj 10) 
    (conj 1))

#{90 10 1}
```

Now you can call split-at function:

```
(split-at n previous-sorted-set)
```

But that depends on whether you want/can use a sorted set.

Comment: I did need to preserve all the elements in the sequence, so could not use a set in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a possible use for [finger trees](https://github.com/clojure/data.finger-tree)

```
(require '[clojure.data.finger-tree :as ft])
(def css (apply ft/counted-sorted-set (list 6.2 5.1 88.0 90.1 1.2 16.9)))
(ft/ft-split-at css 3)

[(1.2 5.1 6.2) 16.9 (88.0 90.1)]
```